# How to initialize final variable in const constructor for dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to initialize a final variable in constructor, I'm trying to stick with `const` constructor as compiler does some optimzation on const.

```dart
class AnswerExplanation extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color correctOrWrong;
  final Function onNext;
  final Function onPrevious;
  final Question question;
  final String correctOptionText;
  const AnswerExplanation(
      {Key? key,
      required this.correctOrWrong,
      required this.onNext,
      required this.onPrevious,
      required this.question})
      : correctOptionText = question.options
        .firstWhere((element) => element.optionId == question.correctOptionId)
        .optionText,
        super(key: key);

      //rest of the part
}
```

It works fine when I put `correctOptionText = "fixed string"`
inside constructor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in Dart to indicate that a method call can be evaluated at compilation-time, so your `AnswerExplanation` class cannot have a `const` constructor if it must invoke a method (in this case the `question.options` getter) during construction.  Either you will need to give up making it `const` or require that callers supply `correctOptionText`.

Note that the main benefit of the `const` optimization is to avoid needing to construct the same object many times with the same arguments.  It can be useful, but it's not essential.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a constructo you dont need put const just put the constructor like:

you code:

```
  const AnswerExplanation(
      {Key? key,
      required this.correctOrWrong,
      required this.onNext,
      required this.onPrevious,
      required this.question})
```

and put in oher function this part of your code

```
 AnswerExplanation(
      {Key? key,
      required this.correctOrWrong,
      required this.onNext,
      required this.onPrevious,
      required this.question})
```

and the Flutter  U dont need define the constructor.